# GWT RegExp - multiple matches

Tags: java, regex, gwt, jsoup

I want to find all the "code" matches in my input string (With GWT RegExp). When I call the "regExp.exec(inputStr)" method it only returns the first match, even when I call it multiple times:

```
String input = "ff <code>myCode</code> ff <code>myCode2</code> dd <code>myCode3</code>";

String patternStr = "<code[^>]*>(.+?)</code\\s*>";

// Compile and use regular expression
RegExp regExp = RegExp.compile(patternStr);
MatchResult matcher = regExp.exec(inputStr);

boolean matchFound = (matcher != null); // equivalent to regExp.test(inputStr); 
if (matchFound) {
    // Get all groups for this match
    for (int i=0; i<matcher.getGroupCount(); i++) {
        String groupStr = matcher.getGroup(i);
        System.out.println(groupStr);
    }
}
```

How can I get all the matches?

**Edit:** Like greedybuddha noted: A regex is not really suited to parse (X)HTML. I gave JSOUP a try and it is much more convienient than with a regex. My code with jsoup now looks like this. I am renaming all code tags and apply them a CSS-Class:

```
    String input = "ff<code>myCode</code>ff<code>myCode2</code>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");

Elements links = doc.select("code"); // a with href

for(Element link : links){
    System.out.println(link.html());
    link.tagName("pre");
    link.addClass("prettify");
}

System.out.println(doc);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile the regular expression with the "g" [flag](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/regexp/shared/RegExp.html#compile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), for global matching.

```
RegExp regExp = RegExp.compile(patternStr,"g");
```

I think you will also want "m" for multiline matching, `"gm"`.

That being said, for HTML/XML parsing you should consider using JSoup or another alternative.

Comment: Thanks, i switched to JSOUP and it much more convinient!